# How to successfully call C code on super computer using ucminf package in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to run the some unconstrained optimization on a large problem on
a super computer, so I am trying to use the ucminf (although this problem
also works if I use the ucminf option in optimx). When I run any simple
optimization, I get the following message:

> Error in .Call("mfopt", fnstr, grstr, rho, PACKAGE = "ucminf") :
>   "mfopt" not available for .Call() for package "ucminf"

For simplicity, here is a simple bit of test code that gives me the error.

```
library(ucminf)
test<-function(x){
(x-3)^2}

ucminf(0,test)
```

All of this works fine on my personal computer, but does not work on the
super computer. I have tried this on R/3.5.0 and R/3.3.0 on the super
computer and they both give me the same error.

Here is my Session info.

```
    R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/public/R/3.5.0.gnu/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/public/R/3.5.0.gnu/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.iso885915       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.iso885915        LC_COLLATE=en_US.iso885915
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.iso885915    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.iso885915
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.iso885915       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C                   LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.iso885915 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] ucminf_1.0-5      numDeriv_2016.8-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the package using Rinstall('ucminf'). Does anyone have experience with this and how to fix it?

Comment: @Artem While I agree more information is needed, I think OP has clearly *tried* to provide an MCVE -- they pared down R code to the shortest they could that causes the error for them. As such, I think suggestions of what other information could be useful would be more productive. For example, the output of `sessionInfo()` is typically useful in this type of situations, as is an explanation of *how* you installed `ucminf`.

Comment: GitHub issues for other packages on similar error messages suggest re-installing the package and/or restarting R as a potential fix ([example](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1964), [another example](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/99)). Have you tried that?

Comment: @duckmayr, fair enough.I'll remove the comment. Thanks for your pointing out.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the command `Rinstall()`. Is that run from R (and if so, what package provides that command?), or from the command line?

Comment: 'Installed package as following: R install command: install.packages("ucminf", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")'

Any other suggestion?